# Capture output from Powershell version 2

Tags: c#, powershell, process, powershell-2.0, stdout

I am having trouble capturing the output from Powershell version 2.
I use the regular Process class to run the program and handle input and output and everything works great. Working code below:

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
  p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  p.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell";
  //p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => AddRow(args.Data);
  p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => AddRow("ERR: " + args.Data);

  p.Start();

  ps = p.StandardInput;
  p.BeginOutputReadLine();
  p.BeginErrorReadLine();

  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  ps.WriteLine("dir");
  Thread.Sleep(100);

  while (true)
  {
      Thread.Sleep(10);
  }
}
```

This version starts powershell and sends "dir" to stdinput of the process and the result is sent back to stdout. I can see the cmd-window but i cant write or see any output there as expected. (I know i can hide it).

But then i add this row:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-version 2";
```

This is to start powershell in version 2 and now it just prints 2 rows that tells me powershell is started and then the connection is lost.
I see in the console window that the cursor is blinking and now i can interact with powershell in the command window since the connection to my process class is lost. When i enter "exit" in the window i am back again to my process.

How can i solve this?

Full code (when using version 2 that is not working) below:

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
  p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  p.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell";
  p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-version 2";
  //p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => AddRow(args.Data);
  p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => AddRow("ERR: " + args.Data);
  p.Start();

  ps = p.StandardInput;
  p.BeginOutputReadLine();
  p.BeginErrorReadLine();

  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  ps.WriteLine("dir");
  Thread.Sleep(100);

  while (true)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(10);
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this! Thanks for your time!

Comment: `I can see the cmd-window but i cant write or see any output there as expected. (I know i can hide it).` It is confusing... Is running without "-version 2" working as expected or not?

Comment: Sorry, I will clarify.  Without "-version 2" everything works as expected. This means that stdin and stdout are going through c# and not the console window. But when i add "-version 2", which is what i want, stdin and stdout are disconnected from c# and i can write in the console window which should not be possible since that means that stdin and stdout are back in the console and not connected to c#.

Comment: OK. But out of curiosity, why do u have to use version 2? PS is backward compatible.

Comment: As i understood it (trying to help a collegue) they need version 2 since they use Sharepoint cmdlets that only works on version 2.

Comment: Seems so weired that it works for all programs except for Powershell when downgrading to version 2??